# Switch returns no value

Tags: java, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that includes a radio button, and I'm trying to turn the radio button into a "bootstrap switch" (http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/). This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="true">
<script>
    $ ('[name="myRadio"]').bootstrapSwitch();
</script>
```

My radio button gets replaced with a bootstraps switch, but it's value is set to null regardless of wether the switch is turned on or off. If I remove the script and use a plain radio button, everything works as it's supposed to.

I want to retrieve the radio button value in a servlet like this:

```
String value = request.getParameter("myRadio");
```

What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Attach switchChange event to bootstarp switch and then get it's state like

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
$('input[name="my-checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
  console.log(this); // DOM element
  console.log(event); // jQuery event
  console.log(state); // true | false
});
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. Now the code looks like: http://pastebin.com/ttmnUi7s. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: I think assign boolean value to it's state

Comment: According to your logic, your taking its state whether true or false.but again your assigning the same to itself.

Comment: So how should I set the value in such a way that it is accessible from  a servlet?

Answer (score 0):

This is for those who have paired radio buttons with Enable/Disable kind of values

**Original HTML:**

```
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="radio_active" VALUE="Yes" onClick="trunOff(0)" checked>Activated
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="radio_active" VALUE="No" onClick="turnOff(1)">Deactivated
```

**Replace above with HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="radio_active" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" value="Yes" data-onchange="trunOff">

<input type="checkbox" class="bs-switch-radio" data-hidden="radio_active" data-size="small" data-label-width="auto" data-on-text="&nbsp;Activated&nbsp;" data-off-text="&nbsp;Deactivated&nbsp;" checked />
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.bs-switch-radio').bootstrapSwitch();
jQuery('.bs-switch-radio').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(e,state){
    var hidden = jQuery(this).attr('data-hidden');
    var jhidden = jQuery("input[name='"+hidden+"']");
    var on = (jhidden.attr('data-on'))? jhidden.attr('data-on'): 1;
    var off = (jhidden.attr('data-off'))? jhidden.attr('data-off'): 0;
    var state_val = (state)? on : off;
    jhidden.val(state_val);

    var fnOnchange = jhidden.attr('data-onchange');
    var fn = window[fnOnchange];
    if(typeof fn === 'function') {
        fn(state);
    }
});
```